# Need help using AirDrop between iPhone 8 Plus and MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, airdrop

I have an iPhone 8 Plus and a MacBook Air early 2014. I've been trying to use airdrop, but my iPhone is not finding my computer.

Both devices Wi-Fi is on and connected, as is Bluetooth. On my MacBook I can see the AirDrop screen, but that's it. I need help figuring out what to do in order to airdrop from my phone to the computer. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask whether you've had a chance to search other questions/answers on this site? There's quite a few of them that may solve your problem. Also, it's not clear from your question as to whether you've actually tried transferring a file from your iPhone to your MBA?

Comment: I’m having exact same issue I think same models too funnily enough.. I am operating on OS X Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 1):

I'm now 100% sure, but because of the old operating system on the computer, there could be some compatibility issues. If your able to I would suggest upgrading to El Captain, macOS Sierra or if your computer can support it, macOS High Sierra. You can upgrade it via the App Store.